# Play 2.0 Java: Can't pass List into template

Tags: list, templates, playframework

I am trying to pass a list of questions into a template in Play 2.0.

The controller code looks like this:

```
List<Question> questions = Question.findAll();
return ok(questions.render("Here are all the questions", questions));
```

The Template constructor looks like this

```
 @(message: String, questions: List[Question])
```

The template file is called `questions.scala.html`

I also use the questions list like this later in the template:

```
@questions_list(questions)
```

and the constructor for `questions_list.scala.html) looks like this:

```
@(questions: List[Question])
```

I am getting the compile error:

```
cannot find symbol [symbol: method render(java.lang.String,
java.util.List<models.Question>)] 
[location: interface java.util.List<models.Question>]
```

I have tried cleaning and recompiling with no luck? Does anybody see whats wrong here?

Comment: Does the constructor is located at the beginning of the view file ?

Comment: The error is shown in Eclipse, or in the browser when you hit reload ?

Comment: the error is shown in the browser, but I also strangely have errors in eclipse on all my `.render()` calls, though it hasn't been causing problems. Eclipse shows the error `the method render(String, List<Question>) is undefined for type List<Question>

Comment: I have the same issue with Eclipse... But for your problem, I don't have any idea, sorry :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so the problem was a naming collision between my template and the variable name I was assigning to the `List<Question>`. I think I may start naming my templates with uppercase to more properly illustrate that that they are classes when I am using them in controllers.